# Specify a character encoding using HTTP Content-Type header

Tags: php, html

I use the W3C mobileOK checker and it suggests me to specify a character encoding using HTTP Content-Type header. How can I do it using

```
header();
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your encoding:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```